# Configuration Error - Insufficient Permissions

Tags: .net, permissions, dotnetopenauth

I just downloaded the template for DotNetOpenAuth 3.4 and created a new project from the template. Open starting the web server in Visual Studio and launching the setup page I am greeted with the following error after providing my OpenId:

> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during
>   the processing of a configuration file
>   required to service this request.
>   Please review the specific error
>   details below and modify your
>   configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Insufficient
>   permissions for setting the
>   configuration property
>   'checkCertificateRevocationList'.

I tried going into the project folder and adding 'Everyone' to the permissions tab, but it had no effect. It still throws the above error when trying to access the web.config file.

How do I go about giving the correct permissions to the code running inside the development server that comes with Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding in full trust into your web.config file:

```
   <trust level="Full" />
```

It may be that your IIS is set to a lower trust level preventing dotnetopenauth from functioning.

If that isn't it then can we see the rest of the error?  If your in debug mode you should be able to show the source of the error.  This particular error might not even be caused by dotnetopenauth...  Basically the error is saying that you cannot set a configuration property, like how we set the trust property of "level" to full.  So show us the part of your configuration file where this checkCertificateRevocationList property is set.

Comment: I hate all this configuration that comes with web applications. Adding full level trust in the web config fixed the issue.